# How to create a webpage that shows a number with increment,decrement buttons and that counts down from the NUmber to zero?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a website with HTML, JAvascript and CSS,
There will be a number showing in the screen. THe user can decrement or increment the preset value using buttons.Start /stop button will start counting down from the shown number to zero. The page shows an alertbox when the number reaches zero. I know only html and css basics can anybody help[This is a rough sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0G74.png)

Comment: You should attempt to learn some javascript basics and try to write your own code. Then you can narrow your problems down to a specific problem. If you want to learn an easy Javascript framework that will help you build this, I suggest you go through [these tutorials](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics) on Svelte.js

Answer (score 0):

This may help get you started:

```js
var intvl;
var valueContainer = document.getElementById("value");
document.getElementById("decrement").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var value = +valueContainer.textContent;
  if(value){
    valueContainer.textContent = value - 1;
  }
});
document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var value = +valueContainer.textContent;
  valueContainer.textContent = value + 1;
});
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(intvl){
    clearInterval(intvl);
  } else {
    var curr = +valueContainer.textContent;
    intvl = setInterval(function(){
      if(curr){
        valueContainer.textContent = --curr;
      } else {
        clearInterval(intvl);
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "Alert<br/>----------------<br/>Count reached 0!";
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
});
document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  clearInterval(intvl);
  valueContainer.textContent = 25;
  document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = "";
});
```

```css
#messages {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2px;
}

#wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

#main > button, #controls > button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

#controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="messages">
&nbsp;
</div>
<div id="main">
<button id="decrement">-</button>
<span id="value">25</span>
<button id="increment">+</button>
</div><br/>
<div id="controls">
<button id="toggle">Start/Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
```